# Passing data from Facebook to an iFrame application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to build a Facebook application for my website. The website allows students to book lessons with an instructor.

I want an instructor to be able to have an app on their page which allows their Facebook fans to book a lesson using the Facebook application.

This would be fairly simple, however I don't want each instructor to have their own App ID. I want to create one app, register one app with Facebook and get one app ID.

Ideally, something should be passed from Facebook to my application. So the URL would be:

www.mydomain.com/facebook-integration?facebookPageID=THE_PAGE_ID

I can then display the correct page within the iFrame application in Facebook.

I'm writing this in ASP.NET MVC, is there a way to get Facebook to send the page ID to my application?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will forward any get/post parameters that are passed from the Facebook app URL to the iframe. So, for example, if you create a link to apps.facebook.com/yourappcanvas?pageid=12345, when Facebook calls your application it will grab www.mydomain.com/facebook-integration?pageid=12345.